# How do i change material.io web component fill-color (mdc-top-app.bar)

Tags: sass, material-components-web

I have been looking into google material design for web and am also totally new to `SASS`. 
As it stands, i have been trying to change the background-color for the `mdc-top-app-bar` using the sass mixin `fill-color($color)` provided in the framework.

**Having tried these few lines**

```
@use '@material/button/mdc-button';
@use '@material/button';
@use "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
@use "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";

.mdc-top-app-bar {
    @include mdc-top-app-bar.fill-color(#8e44ad);
}
```

**Am displayed with the follow error messages**

```
ERROR in ./app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
10 │     @include mdc-top-app-bar.fill-color(#8e44ad);    
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5):

I completely cooked the last answer but I have worked it out.

instead of:

```
@use "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
@use "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";
```

use:

```
@import "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
@import "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";
```

and then to use the mixin,
instead of:

```
.mdc-top-app-bar {
    @include mdc-top-app-bar.fill-color(#8e44ad);
}
```

use:

```
.mdc-top-app-bar {
    @include mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color(#8e44ad);
}
```

I hope this helps

--Nathaniel

Comment: That worked! The dash should be easier to parse than the period. I guess it's name conflicts?

Comment: Yeah i think so

Answer (score 1):

To avoid import statement you should do:

```
@use "@material/top-app-bar";
```

and then

```
.mdc-top-app-bar {
    @include top-app-bar.fill-color(#8e44ad);
}
```

Also you can create alias

```
@use "@material/top-app-bar" as topbar;

.mdc-top-app-bar {
    @include topbar.fill-color(#8e44ad);
}
```